# What's the best regex for validating a comment in python?

Tags: python, regex, django, validation

I want to validate a user's comments in my django project.
In comments, these characters are not allowed:
[ * % & ! = ' ; ` ]

What's the best regex for it?

Comment: Just wondering why you disallow those characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very precisely following your specification, the regex `` ^[^\[\]*%&!=\';`]*$ `` does exactly what you describe. It matches:

```
^              the start of the string
[^             any character that is not:
  *%&!=\';`    any of: [ ] * % & ! = ' ; `
]*             0 or more times
$              the end of the string
```

So in python,

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^[^\[\]*%&!=\';`]*$')
if pattern.match(my_string):
     print('this is a valid comment')
else:
     print('this is an invalid comment')
```

(Beware that your users may be confused about why they may not exclaim! in their comments. Also, if you don't want to match the empty string, use `+` instead of `*`: `` ^[^\[\]*%&!=\';`]+$ ``)

Answer (score 2):

This will allow only words and spaces. If it contain special characters it will discard.

[Check this regular expression here](https://regex101.com/r/uiipaQ/1)

```
^(?!\!\%\!\=\'\;\`)[\w\s\.\?\,]+$
```

Comment: At the risk of going too meta, what about this comment? Your regex would not match it because of the comma, question mark, and period.

Comment: @KernelPanic Sorry. I don't understand. What you talking about?

Comment: This regex doesn't match comments with some "valid" characters. A question mark isn't in the list of disallowed characters, but isn't matched by your regex.

Comment: @KernelPanic Thanks. :) I did changes.

Comment: the list of character that _are_ allowed is far longer than the list that are ;) it'd probably be easier to tell the regex "match anything but this list", rather than "only match this list". For instance, the ^, $, and ) are also allowed but not matched by this regex, and that's just off the top of my head. What about Д, ऄ, or ก?

Comment: (and of course I meant "the list of characters that are allowed is far longer than the list that _aren't_". oh comment edit timeout why do you do this to my tired brain.)

Comment: Right sir! "the list of characters that are allowed is far longer than the list that aren't"